# Pairing of login and logout datetime, and calculate workingtime

Tags: t-sql, join, datediff, row-number

Pair login datetime with logout datetime from single table, and calculate workingtime.

EmployeeLogInOut table:

```
TransactionID bigint,
TransactionDate datetime,
Type smallint,
Automatic bit,
SalesDate datetime,
EmployeeGUID uniqueidentifier,
DepartmentGUID uniqueidentifier
```

See sampledata below.

Type:        1 = LogIn      2 = LogOut

Automatic:    0 = Manual     1 = Automatic

Automatic occure when employee don't log out at end of day. The system will at end of day log out the Employee aoyomaticaly if he/she is not logged out.

It is also possible that an Employee can be logged out atomaticaly when software update occure etc...

For a repport I need to calculate how many minutes an Employee have been logged in to the system at each day(SalesDate).

I trying to get my result into at table like

```
LogOnTime datetime, 
LogOffTime datetime,
DurationInMinute int,
DepartmentGUID uniqueidentifier
```

But because there might not exist an corresponding logOut for each logIn and vise versa, I am getting an error on this approach.

My script:

```
declare @EmployeeGUID uniqueidentifier
declare @StartDate datetime
declare @EndDate datetime

set @EmployeeGUID = 'C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71'
set @StartDate = '09-01-2011'
set @EndDate = '09-30-2011'



create table #result
(
    LogOnTime datetime, 
    LogOffTime datetime,
    DurationInMinute int,
    DepartmentGUID uniqueidentifier
)


    Insert #result(LogOnTime,LogOffTime,DurationInMinute,DepartmentGUID  ) 
    Select A.TransactionDate, B.TransactionDate,datediff(minute,A.TransactionDate, isnull(B.TransactionDate,GetDate())),A.DepartmentGUID
       from 
        (Select Row_number() over (order by TransactionDate) as Num ,* from EmployeeLogInOut 
         where [Type]=1 and  EmployeeGUID = @EmployeeGUID and SalesDate between @StartDate and @EndDate ) as A
        LEFT JOIN  
        (Select Row_number() over (order by TransactionDate) as Num,* from EmployeeLogInOut 
         where [Type]=2   and EmployeeGUID = @EmployeeGUID and SalesDate between @StartDate and @EndDate ) as B
        ON A.Num = B.Num 

    select * from #result
    drop table #result
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeLogInOut(
    [TransactionID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Automatic] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SalesDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO EmployeeLogInOut VALUES 
(2006,'2011-09-05 16:59:39.000',1,0,'2011-09-05 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2008,'2011-09-05 21:57:22.000',2,0,'2011-09-05 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2019,'2011-09-06 16:59:37.000',1,0,'2011-09-06 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2022,'2011-09-06 17:35:41.430',2,0,'2011-09-06 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2039,'2011-09-06 17:36:41.000',2,1,'2011-09-06 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2023,'2011-09-06 17:37:41.000',1,0,'2011-09-06 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2037,'2011-09-07 00:45:32.000',2,0,'2011-09-06 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2054,'2011-09-08 17:12:19.000',1,0,'2011-09-08 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2059,'2011-09-08 20:58:17.000',2,0,'2011-09-08 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2262,'2011-09-20 20:09:10.000',1,0,'2011-09-20 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2269,'2011-09-21 06:59:00.000',2,1,'2011-09-20 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2278,'2011-09-21 17:06:49.000',1,0,'2011-09-21 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2282,'2011-09-21 22:05:29.000',2,0,'2011-09-21 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2283,'2011-09-21 22:06:55.000',1,0,'2011-09-21 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A'),
(2284,'2011-09-21 22:09:04.000',2,0,'2011-09-21 00:00:00.000','C335F76A-E757-48D9-8DFE-01096EEA6A71','520EEFD4-DC30-4390-BB7F-FEFD83D9576A')
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :-)

My thought was that if a corresponding LogIn Datetime does not exist for a LogOut time then the corresponding LogIn Datetime could be set to 06:00 on the actual salesDate.

And if a LogIn Datetime is missing a corresponding LogOut Datetime it could be set to 05:59

Or just ignore all LogIn/LogOut enteries that does not correspond.

PS: I can't change the EmployeeLogInOut table, nor how the data is entered into it.

Comment: It really depends on what the user requirement is.  Do they care if you simply ignore records that don't have login/out times?  If not, then they should be able to specify how missing datetimes should be handled.  Once you know that, we can craft some SQL to match the requirements.

Comment: Thanks for comment, Bernt.  If possible the user want/need to see where a missing corresponding logIn/LogOut exists. For example a LogIn who is missing an matching LogOut could just have it matching LogOut set to NULL, and I could handle that in the rdlc. By showing "Missing value" or something like that in the report field if LogOut.Value = NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some basic code that would work against your sample data but may need further refinement to address your business rules. If you could provide sample data that matches closer your business rules and the expected results according to those rules I could rework the code to work with it.

```
WITH Ranked AS (
--Ranking the rows to clean-up the data.
SELECT  TransactionDate,
        [Type],
        SalesDate,
        --EmployeeGUID and DepartmentGUID should be added to the PARTITION BY section in a real scenario. For the sample data they are irrelevant.
        Sequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SalesDate ORDER BY TransactionDate)
FROM    #EmployeeLogInOut
), Clean AS (
--A more complex clean-up process can be in place here. Right now it just eliminates transactions where the type doesn't alternate from the previous one.
SELECT  TransactionDate,
        [Type],
        SalesDate
FROM    Ranked AS R
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Ranked WHERE SalesDate = R.SalesDate AND Type = R.Type AND Sequence = R.Sequence - 1)
--Previous CTEs can be bypassed and we can reference #EmployeeLogInOut instead of Clean, but we would get some "wrong" output for SalesDate 2011-09-06
), LI AS (
SELECT  SalesDate,
        LogInTime = TransactionDate,
        --EmployeeGUID and DepartmentGUID should be added to the PARTITION BY section in a real scenario. For the sample data they are irrelevant.
        Sequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SalesDate ORDER BY TransactionDate)
FROM    Clean
WHERE   [Type] = 1
), LO AS (
SELECT  SalesDate,
        LogOutTime = TransactionDate,
        --EmployeeGUID and DepartmentGUID should be added to the PARTITION BY section in a real scenario. For the sample data they are irrelevant.
        Sequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SalesDate ORDER BY TransactionDate)
FROM    Clean
WHERE   [Type] = 2
)
SELECT  LI.SalesDate,
    LI.LogInTime,
    LO.LogOutTime,
    WorkTime = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LI.LoginTime, LO.LogoutTime)
FROM    LI 
    LEFT JOIN LO ON LO.SalesDate = LI.SalesDate
        AND LI.Sequence = LO.Sequence;
```

This produces the following results:

```
SalesDate   LogInTime   LogOutTime  WorkTime
2011-09-05 00:00:00.000 2011-09-05 16:59:39.000 2011-09-05 21:57:22.000 298
2011-09-06 00:00:00.000 2011-09-06 16:59:37.000 2011-09-06 17:35:41.430 36
2011-09-06 00:00:00.000 2011-09-06 17:37:41.000 2011-09-07 00:45:32.000 428
2011-09-08 00:00:00.000 2011-09-08 17:12:19.000 2011-09-08 20:58:17.000 226
2011-09-20 00:00:00.000 2011-09-20 20:09:10.000 2011-09-21 06:59:00.000 650
2011-09-21 00:00:00.000 2011-09-21 17:06:49.000 2011-09-21 22:05:29.000 299
2011-09-21 00:00:00.000 2011-09-21 22:06:55.000 2011-09-21 22:09:04.000 3
```